# HSQL Table changes only visable after second progamm run

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I have a program with an HSQL database. However if I run the program it should create some Orders and stuff. But when the programm is corectly shut down it wont save the dates in to "DB.script" i have to runn it a second time that i can see the changes in "DB.script".
Does somebody know the solution to this problem?

Here is how i close the db connection:

```
public void closeAll(Object name){
    session = sf.getCurrentSession();
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.persist(name);
    session.flush();
    session.saveOrUpdate(name);
    transaction.commit();
    org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.closeDatabases(0);
    System.out.println("[Info] Connection Closed");
}
```

And Here My HSQL DB.script:

```
SET DATABASE UNIQUE NAME HSQLDB3D7E03560E
SET DATABASE GC 0
SET DATABASE DEFAULT RESULT MEMORY ROWS 0
SET DATABASE EVENT LOG LEVEL 0
SET DATABASE SQL NAMES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL REGULAR NAMES TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL REFERENCES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL SIZE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TYPES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL TDC DELETE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TDC UPDATE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TRANSLATE TTI TYPES TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL CONCAT NULLS TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL NULLS FIRST TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL UNIQUE NULLS TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL CONVERT TRUNCATE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL AVG SCALE 0
SET DATABASE SQL DOUBLE NAN TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL LONGVAR IS LOB FALSE
SET DATABASE TRANSACTION CONTROL LOCKS
SET DATABASE DEFAULT ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
SET DATABASE TRANSACTION ROLLBACK ON CONFLICT TRUE
SET DATABASE TEXT TABLE DEFAULTS ''
SET FILES WRITE DELAY 0
SET FILES BACKUP INCREMENT TRUE
SET FILES CACHE SIZE 10000
SET FILES CACHE ROWS 50000
SET FILES SCALE 32
SET FILES LOB SCALE 32
SET FILES DEFRAG 0
SET FILES NIO TRUE
SET FILES NIO SIZE 256
SET FILES LOG TRUE
SET FILES LOG SIZE 50
CREATE USER SA PASSWORD DIGEST 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e'
ALTER USER SA SET LOCAL TRUE
CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AUTHORIZATION DBA
SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
CREATE SEQUENCE PUBLIC.SEQU AS INTEGER START WITH 10
CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.ROLLE(ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,ADMIN BOOLEAN,NAME VARCHAR(20))
CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.SORTEBEST(FKKAFFEESORTEN INTEGER NOT NULL,FKBESTELLUNG INTEGER,ANZAHL INTEGER)
CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.KAFFEESORTE(ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,NAME CHARACTER(20),PREIS DOUBLE,TYP CHARACTER(20))
CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.USER(NAME CHARACTER(20),EMAIL VARCHAR(40),FK_ROLLE INTEGER,LOGONID CHARACTER(8) PRIMARY KEY,CONSTRAINT FK_USER_ROLLE FOREIGN KEY(FK_ROLLE) REFERENCES PUBLIC.ROLLE(ID))
CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.BESTELLUNG(ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS SEQUENCE PUBLIC.SEQU NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,FKUSER CHARACTER(8),BESTELLT BOOLEAN,DATUM DATE,CONSTRAINT FK_USER_BEZIEHUNG FOREIGN KEY(FKUSER) REFERENCES PUBLIC.USER(LOGONID))
ALTER SEQUENCE SYSTEM_LOBS.LOB_ID RESTART WITH 0
ALTER SEQUENCE PUBLIC.SEQU RESTART WITH 5
SET DATABASE DEFAULT INITIAL SCHEMA PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.YES_OR_NO TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TIME_STAMP TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CARDINAL_NUMBER TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHARACTER_DATA TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SQL_IDENTIFIER TO PUBLIC
GRANT DBA TO SA
SET SCHEMA SYSTEM_LOBS
INSERT INTO BLOCKS VALUES(0,2147483647,0)
SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
INSERT INTO ROLLE VALUES(1,FALSE,'NORMALER_USER')
INSERT INTO ROLLE VALUES(2,TRUE,'ADMINISTRATOR')
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(1,0,0)
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(2,0,0)
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(3,0,0)
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(4,0,0)
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(5,0,0)
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(6,0,0)
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(7,0,0)
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(8,0,0)
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(9,0,0)
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(10,0,0)
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(11,0,0)
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(12,0,0)
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(13,0,0)
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(14,0,0)
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(15,0,0)
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(1,4,0)
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(2,4,0)
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(3,4,0)
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(4,4,0)
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(5,4,0)
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(6,4,0)
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(7,4,0)
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(8,4,0)
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(9,4,0)
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(10,4,0)
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(11,4,0)
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(12,4,0)
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(13,4,0)
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(14,4,0)
INSERT INTO SORTEBEST VALUES(15,4,0)
INSERT INTO KAFFEESORTE VALUES(1,'Ristretto           ',0.5E0,'Espresso            ')
INSERT INTO KAFFEESORTE VALUES(2,'Arpeggio            ',0.5E0,'Espresso            ')
INSERT INTO KAFFEESORTE VALUES(3,'Roma                ',0.5E0,'Espresso            ')
INSERT INTO KAFFEESORTE VALUES(4,'Livanto             ',0.5E0,'Espresso            ')
INSERT INTO KAFFEESORTE VALUES(5,'Capriccio           ',0.5E0,'Espresso            ')
INSERT INTO KAFFEESORTE VALUES(6,'Volluto             ',0.5E0,'Espresso            ')
INSERT INTO KAFFEESORTE VALUES(7,'Cosi                ',0.5E0,'Espresso            ')
INSERT INTO KAFFEESORTE VALUES(8,'Decaffeinato Intenso',0.5E0,'Decaffeinato        ')
INSERT INTO KAFFEESORTE VALUES(9,'Decaffeinato        ',0.5E0,'Decaffeinato        ')
INSERT INTO KAFFEESORTE VALUES(10,'Decaffeinato Lungo  ',0.52E0,'Decaffeinato        ')
INSERT INTO KAFFEESORTE VALUES(11,'Fortissio Lungo     ',0.52E0,'Lungo               ')
INSERT INTO KAFFEESORTE VALUES(12,'Vivalto Lungo       ',0.52E0,'Lungo               ')
INSERT INTO KAFFEESORTE VALUES(13,'Linizio Lungo       ',0.52E0,'Lungo               ')
INSERT INTO KAFFEESORTE VALUES(14,'Indriya from India  ',0.57E0,'Pure Orgin          ')
INSERT INTO KAFFEESORTE VALUES(15,'Rosabaya de Colombia',0.57E0,'Pure Orgin          ')
INSERT INTO USER VALUES('Jonas            ','test@hotmail.com',2,'324     ')
INSERT INTO BESTELLUNG VALUES(0,'234    ',TRUE,'2013-04-26')
INSERT INTO BESTELLUNG VALUES(1,'234    ',TRUE,'2013-04-29')
INSERT INTO BESTELLUNG VALUES(2,'234    ',TRUE,'2013-04-29')
INSERT INTO BESTELLUNG VALUES(3,'234    ',TRUE,'2013-04-29')
INSERT INTO BESTELLUNG VALUES(4,'234    ',TRUE,'2013-04-29')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in the HSQL [manual](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch01.html#N1023C) :

> Memory tables are the default type when the CREATE TABLE command is
>   used. Their data is held entirely in memory but any change to their
>   structure or contents is written to the .script file. The
>   script file is read the next time the database is opened, and the
>   MEMORY tables are recreated with all their contents. So unlike TEMP
>   table, the default, MEMORY tables are persistent.

Comment: Instead of using an unsupported internal method to close the database, connect to the database and execute the SQL statement: `SHUTDOWN`. This will write the data to the .script file.

Comment: @fredt Thanks allot now i can see the changes right after closing :)